# How to prevent repl.it WebSocket from going to sleep?

Tags: websocket, html

I have a WebSocket hosting on repl.it

But when the repl sleeps, the WebSocket does as well.

My friends told me to have a pinger to ping the site. It doesn't work.

They told me to fetch the server.

That doesn't work either, because when the repl sleeps, CORS is disabled although my code enables CORS.

What do I do?

SERVER CODE (NODEJS):

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const WebSocket = require("ws")
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('release'));
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));

app.use((_, res) => {
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/error/404.html'));
});

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    fs.readFile("highscore.txt", 'utf-8', (err, val) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        wss.clients.forEach(client => {
            if (client === ws) {
                client.send(`I ${val}`)
            }
        })
        console.log(val);
    });

    console.log('socket connected!');

    ws.on("message", msg => {
        let msgs = msg.split(" ");
        let pre = msgs[0]
        if (pre == "R") {
            fs.readFile("highscore.txt", 'utf-8', (err, val) => {
                let score = msgs[1]
                if (err) throw err;
                if (val < score) {
                    console.log(`There is a new score! That is:${score}`);
                    fs.writeFile('highscore.txt', score, (err) => { })
                    wss.clients.forEach(client => {
                        client.send(`U ${score}`)
                    })
                };
            });
        }
    });
});

server.listen(2195, () => {
    console.log(`server running`);
});
```

CLIENT CODE

````
import { loadProgress } from './main'
let socket;

function init(details) {
    fetch("https://space-chaos--coder2195text.repl.co")
        .then(response => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(final => {
            console.log(final)
            loadProgress.update("ws", 100)
            socket = new WebSocket("wss://space-chaos--coder2195text.repl.co/")
            socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
                let msgs = msg.data.split(" ")
                if (msgs[0] === "U") {
                    details.update(msgs[1])
                } else if (msgs[0] === "I") {
                    details.init(msgs[1])
                }
            }
        })
}

function requestPush(score) {
    let t = setInterval(() => {
        if (socket) {
            if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                socket.send(`R ${score}`);
                clearInterval(t)
            }
        }
    }, 100)
}

export { requestPush, init };
```
````

Comment: It sounds like you might want to upgrade to the always-on version at $7/month if you want always-on functionality.

Comment: ok imma causally pull money out of thin air... that's not a solution -_-

Comment: Can I perhaps use iframes?

Comment: Hard to say without more details about your setup. We know you're using WebSocket, we don't know how you're using it or what you're using it for. We know you tried a ping, but we don't know *how* you tried a ping. We know you tried to "fetch the server", but we don't know *how* you tried doing that. A vague question tends to attract only vague answers, or none at all.

Comment: iframe I could make the repl boot up, and once the iframe is loaded, I can guarantee the socket has opened. 
or I can keep fetching until the server boots up, because I noticed even though a CORS error occurred, the server booted up

Comment: By the way github code is here https://github.com/Coder2195Text/space-chaos

Comment: I recommend **editing your question** so that it contains the code a reader would need to review to understand your situation, not an off-site link to your full repository. Remember that users here are volunteers. If they have to trawl hundreds of lines of code in a repository just to judge whether this is a question they can help with, they'll probably just click away to the next question instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125035/discussion-between-coder2195-and-dmgregory).